# SQL Server - Order By Ascend seems to not be working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a DB that creates records for users, and they can create new versions of these records.  I keep track of the old records, so I differentiate it by adding in a column (VARCHAR(20)) in my DB that stores the version of the data.  I created a stored procedure that takes the rows that match the user's ID, and orders the versions in a string with the versions separated by '|'.  This was working for a while, but recently a user created a 10th version, and somehow this flow seems to break.  Below is the SP:

```
DECLARE @IN_vsId VARCHAR(100)

SET @IN_vsId='user1'
SELECT @Version_str = COALESCE(@Version_str + '|', '') + VSN_NO 
FROM (
SELECT TOP 100 VSN_NO
FROM table1 myTable
WHERE myTable.ID = @IN_vsId
ORDER BY myTable.VSN_NO ASC
)VERSION_TBL

PRINT @Version_str
```

When the user had <9 versions, the string would look like `1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9`.  However, once the 10th version was created, it now looks like `1|10|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9`.  I'm at a loss here.  My backend relies on getting the length of the list (I convert it to a List once I return from my SP) and fetching the last index, which would always be 9 in this case.  I can change this in the backend by just getting the max int from the list, but I want to see if I can change my DB first.

**EDIT**
The answers so far work well, except I had some versions with a 'P' in front with certain types of user data.  I added if else statements to detect if the row will have a 'P' version, and then made:

```
DECLARE @Version_str VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @IN_vsId VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @IN_vsType VARCHAR(100)

SET @IN_vsId='user1'

IF @IN_vsType='DRAFT'
BEGIN
    SELECT @Version_str = COALESCE(@Version_str + '|', '') + VSN_NO 
    FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 VSN_NO
    FROM table1 myTable
    WHERE myTable.ID = @IN_vsId
    AND myTable.TYPE_NM = @IN_vsType
    )VERSION_TBL ORDER BY TRY_CAST(VSN_NO AS INT) ASC
END
IF @IN_vsType='PUBLISH'
BEGIN
SELECT @Version_str = COALESCE(@Version_str + '|', '') + VSN_NO 
    FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 VSN_NO
    FROM table1 myTable
    WHERE myTable.ID = @IN_vsId
    AND myTable.TYPE_NM = @IN_vsType
    )VERSION_TBL ORDER BY TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(VSN_NO, 2, LEN(VSN_NO)) AS INT) ASC 
END

PRINT @Version_str
```

In the case of a P, I make a substring that removes the P, and cast the numbers as int as I'm ordering them

Comment: The problem here is storing numbers as strings. Store the version numbers at int and this problem fixes itself.

Comment: @SeanLange While Ideally that would be the case, I inherited this DB schema, and I can't make changes to the column types anymore, have to work with what I got :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, a table represent an *unordered* sets of row. You need an `order by` clause to order your data. It does not matter that you did order the results of the inner query. From the perspective of the outer query, the dataset that is returned by the inner query is just that: an unordered set of rows. You need to do the ordering in the outer query.

Another problem is that you seem to be storing numbers as strings. String ordering rules are not the same as for numeric datatypes (typically, string-wise, `'2` is greater than `'10'`). You can cast to a numeric datatype before sorting:

```
SET @IN_vsId='user1'
SELECT @Version_str = COALESCE(@Version_str + '|', '') + VSN_NO 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 VSN_NO
    FROM table1 myTable
    WHERE myTable.ID = @IN_vsId
    ORDER BY CAST(VSN_NO AS INT) ASC
) VERSION_TBL
ORDER BY CAST(VSN_NO AS INT) ASC
```

If there is a risk that some values can't be converted to a number, you can use:

```
ORDER BY TRY_CAST(VSN_NO AS INT) ASC
```

Comment: Let me try running this locally

Comment: Unfortunately this is still giving the same response, using `VERSION_TBL ORDER BY VSN_NO ASC`

Comment: Even with the `CAST`, this is still incorrect. The nested `SELECT` also needs an `ORDER BY` in case there are more than 100 rows.

Comment: @LaughingVergil: correct, it needs order by too, so the `TOP 100` is honoured. I added it.

Comment: @GMB We have some versions that are pre-fixed with a `P` to denote a special version, would it break that?

Comment: @user3334871: how do you want to sort those versions? `'P'` cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Same sort, just with a P in front, so the versions should go `P1|P2|P3|...`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the version is `varchar`, and not numeric of some type.  In this case, the values are being added as '1', '2', '10', etc.

When sorting a string, you compare the first characters first, then the second one, etc.  So, when sorted alphabetically, this is correct:

```
1
10
2
20
```

You need these values to be either zero padded:

```
01
02
10
20
```

or to use a numeric field (int, numeric, etc) if you want them to sort correctly.

Now, considering your new information above (some codes start with a letter), the task becomes more complex but not unmanageable. Try this for your ORDER BY statement (assumes only one alpha character before numbers, does not assume that something can not have codes with both alpha and only numeric):

```
ORDER BY CASE
    When IsNumeric(VSN_NO) = 1
        THEN RIGHT('000000' + VSN_NO, 6) -- assumes a max of six characters
    ELSE Left(VSN_NO, 1) + RIGHT('00000' + SUBSTRING(VSN_NO, 2, LEN(VSN_NO)), 5)
END ASC
```

Comment: You could also ORDER BY (CAST mytable.VSN_NO AS int) ASC

Comment: @pmbAustin agreed, but it would be less efficient.

Comment: @pmbAustin Let me try to cast it, the easiest change would be to the SP and not the DB architecture (corporate use case)

Comment: Yes, it would not be efficient, and it could fail if any of the values are not castable to int. But it's a short-term hack solution until a real one can be put into place. And the performance depends entirely on how many rows the result set returns. If it's less than hundreds, it's fine. If it's more than thousands, probably not.

Comment: @LaughingVergil This is not a high traffic app, so we don't have to worry about efficiency (We don't plan to scale)

Comment: @LaughingVergil I think I found a solution for the P problem, it seems to work when I test it. Let me put it in my question